# The attribute must be specified in the format of "Name:Type:Label", where "Type" and "Label" are optional

Tags: yii, cdetailview

I have two models/mysql tables: `User` and `Truck`.
In my Truck table I have row user_id and in my `Truck _form.php` I created `dropDownList` field `user_id` which is populating from `User` table.
Code:

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'user_id', CHtml::listData(User::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name')); ?>
```

And it works fine, I manage to list all Users in my dropdown. But when I save form data it should redirect me to `CDetailView` but instead i get this error:

> "The attribute must be specified in the format of "Name:Type:Label", where "Type" and "Label" are optional."

Could someone tell me what's causing this problem, I tried to set relations and everything but still get this error..
Thanks

Comment: share your detailview code, and full stacktrace, the error seems be in the display of detailView and not in the form

Comment: could you post your Truck model rules ?

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for replay, meanwhile I created fresh new project and it works. In my old project I changed my database structure few times, I guess this could cause the problem. Could you please tell me how can I clear all cache memory in Yii app so I can try that?

Comment: there are different types of caches yii supports, see here for list http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.overview. Clearing depends on which type of cache you want to clear